# How to achieve desirable result using regexp_replace function in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, regexp-replace, apache-spark-dataset

**Suppose the data is -**

```
"King Khaled Hospital """"NG"""""
```

length (including quotes and spaces) = 33

In above example:

1. Keep the starting and ending quotes intact means position 1 & position 33
2. before NG, there are 4 double quotes. So make them only 1.
3. After NG, there are 5 double quotes at the position of 29, 30, 31, 32, 33.
   33th double quotes should be remain as it is beacause it is ending one. 29, 30, 31, 32 should convert into 1 double quotes.

**Final output:**

```
"King Khaled Hospital "NG""
```

length = 27

It is just an exaple. Data can be anything.

Let me give one post example:

My df:

```
>>>
>>> df.select('full_nm').where(df['eid'] == '60806998').show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|full_nm                                                                                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""King Khaled Hospital """"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""NG"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Final output:**

```
"King Khaled Hospital "NG""
```

If I am using below code:

```
>>> df_temp = df.withColumn('full_nm', regexp_replace('full_nm', r'("{2,})([^"]+)\1', r'"$2"'))
>>> df_temp.select('full_nm').where(df_temp['eid'] == '60806998').show(truncate=False)
23/11/13 08:58:51 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|full_nm                                  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|"King Khaled Hospital ""NG"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: You can use substring function and then for internal quotes, you can use string replace.

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-substring-from-a-column/

Answer (score 1):

Setup

```
df.show()

+---------------------------------+
|col                              |
+---------------------------------+
|"King Khaled Hospital """"NG"""""|
|foo ""baz""                      |
|"foo bar"                        |
|"foo """bar""" ""baz"""          |
|"""foo"""                        |
+---------------------------------+
```

Let us use regexp_replace to substitute the two or more consecutive occurrences of quotes with a single quote.Just keep in mind that here I am assuming that the strings in your dataset is always sorrounded by same number of quotes for instance if a word is preceded by 4 quotes then it must be followed by 4 quotes

```
result = df.withColumn('clean_col', F.regexp_replace('col', r'("{2,})([^"]+)\1', r'"$2"'))
```

Result

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
|col                              |clean_col                  |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
|"King Khaled Hospital """"NG"""""|"King Khaled Hospital "NG""|
|foo ""baz""                      |foo "baz"                  |
|"foo bar"                        |"foo bar"                  |
|"foo """bar""" ""baz"""          |"foo "bar" "baz""          |
|"""foo"""                        |"foo"                      |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, I added few lines in my question. Please have a look and thank you for response.

Comment: Quotes can be any number.

Comment: Hi, shall I get any response please?

Comment: Left & right side number of quotes can be vary also

Comment: Lemme look into it in sometime.

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Comment: Hi Shubham, do you have any update on this please?

Comment: Since you don't have any predefined pattern it would be very difficult to remove the quotes simply using regular expressions..there can be several edge cases.

Comment: Ohkk. Thank you for your time. Do you any other way not with regular expression?

Comment: 1 quotes is changing into 2, 2 is changing into 4. Means process doubling the quotes everytime.

Comment: Can we do using spark sql?